# How to revert the SameSite cookie changes introduced by KB4533097

Tags: .net, iis, session-cookies

Since my windows server got this update all my .net websites don't work anymore with cross domain form posting. This is for internal systems so I'm not worried about CSRF.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution:

Add

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
  <httpCookies sameSite="None" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="{yourName}" cookieSameSite="None" />
  </authentication>
<system.web>
```